# GitHub Action create repo and copy content of directory on a loop through JSON file

Tags: github, github-actions

I am newbie in GitHub Action. Trying to create an action that reads the JSON file for any changes and create new repo (skips if repo exists) if there is new repo name updated in the JSON. Also it copies some directory to new repo's root upon creation. Here is the tree per my best understanding.

### Central_Repo

```
.github
    |- workflows
        |- create_repo.yaml
org.json
template_dir
    |- fileA
    |- fileB
scripts
    |- create_repo.py
```

### org.json

```
[{
    "projectA": [{
            "repo_name": "repoA",
            "repo_key": "ABC_TOKEN"
        },
        {
            "repo_name": "repoB",
            "repo_key": "ABC_TOKEN"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Tried different approach and did a lot googling for a suitable GitHub Native action but unable to construct the whole thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
name: Create Repo
on: 
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  TEMPLATE_DIR: template_dir
  SCRIPTS_DIR: scripts

jobs:
  build:
    name: Create Repo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check out template repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: ORG1/Central_Repo
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        path: ${{ env.TEMPLATE_DIR }}

 #   - name: Run repository configuration
 #     run: python ${{ env.SCRIPTS_DIR}}/create_repo.py
 #     shell: sh
```

OR:

```
name: Clone Private Repository Workflow
on:
  push:
   branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-repo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Clone repo-template private repository
        uses: ORG1/repo-template
        with:
          repository: 'repoA'
          access-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      
      - name: Access cloned repository content
        run: |
          echo "ROOT"
          ls -la
          echo "CLONED REPO"
          cd formulas-training
          ls -la
```

Comment: This isn't what you're asking for, but have you considered using Terraform and its [GitHub provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs) instead of trying to build it yourself?

Comment: As for cloning manually, you could use the GitHub CLI in a `run` step with the endpoint at `/repos/{template_owner}/{template_repo}/generate` (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-repository-using-a-template))

Comment: ok going through it

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thats the API. Is there native action that can create repo based on json input? I can open another section and run a script later to copy content.

Comment: I can't find one that creates from template, only for cloning.